# how sort appended data jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have one `for` loop that gets data from the server sorted descending, but in `append()` the data sort is not working. For example, the first row show in second position.

How can I append data exactly as it's sorted from the server side data?

```js
$(document).on('click', '#jhchat', function() {
  $('.jhchat').find('.messagemoda').html('');
  var jus = '{{Auth::user()->id}}';
  
  $.ajax({
    url: '{{url("getuchats")}}',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
      _token: CSRF_TOKEN
    },
    success: function(data) {
      if (data.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          if (data[0].s_id == jus) {
            var mid = data[i].r_id;
          } else {
            var mid = data[i].s_id;
          }
          $.ajax({
            url: '{{url("getchatdet")}}',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
              _token: CSRF_TOKEN,
              'mid': mid,
              'chid': data[i].id
            },
            success: function(res) {
              $('.jhchat').find('.messagemoda').append(`
                <div class="row mt-3 conv` + res.chat.id + `" alt="` + res.chat.id + `">
                  <div class="col-11 row mt-2 ads chads cchat` + res.chat.id + `" alt="` + res.chat.id + `" id="` + res.mid + `">
                    <div class="col-3" style="padding-left: 5px;">
                      <img src="` + res.img + `" alt="home" width="60" height="60" class="rounded-circle">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                      <h6 class="mt-4 text-end">` + res.name + ' ' + (res.mescount > 0 ? '<span class="me-4" style="color: crimson;background-color: bisque;border-radius: 50%;padding-left: 5px;padding-right: 5px;">' + res.mescount + '</span>' : '') + `</h6>
                    </div>           
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-1 mt-4 ps-0 ms-0 float-start text-start" style="position: relative;">
                    <img src="{{url('images/menu.png')}}" alt="` + res.chat.id + `" width="32px" height="32px" class="hmenu" style="cursor: pointer;background-color: #eee;border-radius: 50%;padding:8px;">
                    <div class="smenu` + res.chat.id + ` jsmen">` + (res.justo > 0 ? '<a class="me-2 jsmenitem d-block" href="' + res.s + '">go store <img style="margin-right: 2rem;" src="{{url('images / arrow1.png ')}}" width="13px" height="13px"></a>' : '') + `
                      <p class="text-danger delconv mt-2 mb-0 me-2 jsmenitem" alt="` + res.chat.id + `" style="cursor: pointer;">delete <img style="margin-right: 3.4rem;" src="{{url('images/close1.png')}}" width="10px" height="10px"></p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>`);
            }
          });
        }
        $(".messagemoda").trigger("update");
      } else {
        $('.jhchat').find('.messagemoda').html('<div class="mt-5 text-center">no data</div>');
      }
    }
  });

  $('.adsopa').css('opacity', '0.3');
  $('.sidebarmenu').removeClass('active');
  $('.jhchat').css("display", "block");
  $('body').css('overflow-y', 'hidden');
});
```

Comment: The problem will be because you're sending off multiple AJAX requests in your `for` loop and they will all be returned at different times due to them being asynchronous. To fix this (and improve performance and reduce server costs) stop sending AJAX requests in a loop. Send a single array in a single request and return all relevant data from that one request. Also - why are you concatenating template literals? The whole point of them is to use interpolation, not concatenation.

Comment: Is there any way to fetch all of the data you need with a single request instead of a separate request for every record?  Because what's likely happening here is that the requests are completing in a random order (being asynchronous and all).  Alternatively you could hold the resulting data in an in-memory array and re-sort/re-render after each completed request.  But the simplest approach would likely be to be able to do this operation in a single request.

Answer (score 0):

And as pointed out in the comments, you should get all data in one request if you have the backend, which can provide it as such. These multiple request could not be received in the order you send them - you have no control over the magic of the network if self.

Comment: That's not how `append()` works. If you append B after A, the order will always be A, B. You seem to be confusing `append()` with something like `after()`, or `insertAfter()`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you are right - `append()` inserts an element at the end of the target as a child, not as a sibling. Thanks. I've deleted that part of my answer.